# Display circle in Listbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Hi i want to display different size of circle in List box in asp.net can any buddy tell me code of that

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of circle you want.  Although what Gidon said was right, there are a couple text characters that may just do the job.  These characters you may want to look at are:

● = Black Circle

accessble by using the sequence &#x25CF; in your option text;

○ = White Circle

accessble by using the sequence &#x25CB; in your option text;

Answer (score 0):

The `ListBox` control in ASP.NET renders as a HTML `select` element. This element only accepts text.

This doesn't mean it cannot be done in another way, but you'll have to write your own implementation, using javascript etc.

Based on your question I'm not sure if you might first want to learn some more HTML, javascript and maybe also ASP.NET before we can discuss the details of such an implementation.